# What is “the inverse side of the association” in a bidirectional JPA OneToMany/ManyToOne association?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, mappedby

In the example section of the [`@OneToMany` JPA annotation reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html):

**Example 1-59 @OneToMany - Customer Class With Generics**

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="customer")
    public Set<Order> getOrders() { 
        return orders; 
    }
    ...
}
```

**Example 1-60 @ManyToOne - Order Class With Generics**

```
@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID", nullable=false)
    public Customer getCustomer() { 
        return customer; 
    }
    ...
}
```

It seems to me that the `Customer` entity is the owner of the association. However, in the explanation for the `mappedBy` attribute in the same document, it is written that:

> if the relationship is bidirectional,
>   then set the mappedBy element on the
>   inverse (non-owning) side of the
>   association to the name of the field
>   or property that owns the relationship
>   as Example 1-60 shows.

However, if I am not wrong, it looks like in the example, the `mappedBy` is actually specified on the owning side of the association, rather than the non-owning side.

So my question is basically:

1. In a bidirectional (one-to-many/many-to-one) association, which of the entities is the owner? How can we designate the One side as the owner? How can we designate the Many side as the owner?
2. What is meant by "the inverse side of the association"? How can we designate the One side as the inverse? How can we designate the Many side as the inverse?

Comment: the link you provided is outdated. Please update.

Answer (score 327, accepted):

To understand this, you must take a step back. In OO, the customer owns the orders (orders are a list in the customer object). There can't be an order without a customer. So the customer seems to be the owner of the orders.

But in the SQL world, one item will actually contain a pointer to the other. Since there is 1 customer for N orders, each order contains a foreign key to the customer it belongs to. This is the "connection" and this means the order "owns" (or literally contains) the connection (information). This is exactly the opposite from the OO/model world.

This may help to understand:

```
public class Customer {
     // This field doesn't exist in the database
     // It is simulated with a SQL query
     // "OO speak": Customer owns the orders
     private List<Order> orders;
}

public class Order {
     // This field actually exists in the DB
     // In a purely OO model, we could omit it
     // "DB speak": Order contains a foreign key to customer
     private Customer customer;
}
```

The inverse side is the OO "owner" of the object, in this case the customer. The customer has no columns in the table to store the orders, so you must tell it where in the order table it can save this data (which happens via `mappedBy`).

Another common example are trees with nodes which can be both parents and children. In this case, the two fields are used in one class:

```
public class Node {
    // Again, this is managed by Hibernate.
    // There is no matching column in the database.
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // mappedBy is only necessary when there are two fields with the type "Node"
    private List<Node> children;

    // This field exists in the database.
    // For the OO model, it's not really necessary and in fact
    // some XML implementations omit it to save memory.
    // Of course, that limits your options to navigate the tree.
    @ManyToOne
    private Node parent;
}
```

This explains for the "foreign key" many-to-one design works. There is a second approach which uses another table to maintain the relations. That means, for our first example, you have three tables: The one with customers, the one with orders and a two-column table with pairs of primary keys (customerPK, orderPK).

This approach is more flexible than the one above (it can easily handle one-to-one, many-to-one, one-to-many and even many-to-many). The price is that

- it's a bit slower (having to maintain another table and joins uses three tables instead of just two),
- the join syntax is more complex (which can be tedious if you have to manually write many queries, for example when you try to debug something)
- it's more error prone because you can suddenly get too many or too few results when something goes wrong in the code which manages the connection table.

That's why I rarely recommend this approach.

Comment: Just to clarify: the many side is the owner; the one side is the inverse. You don't have a choice (practically speaking).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Aaron. Is there a RDBMS/SQL book available that uses the same terminology (i.e. inverse/owner) where I can find more information about this topic?

What was strange to me also was that the JPA spec didn't have a detailed definition of what inverse means and what owning means. It was just pointed that the mappedBy attribute must be on the inverse side.

Comment: No, Hibernate invented this. I don't like it since it exposes part of the implementation to the OO model. I'd prefer a `@Parent` or `@Child` annotation instead of "XtoY" to state what the connection *means* (rather than how it is *implemented*)

Comment: @AaronDigulla everytime I have to go through a OneToMany mappings I came to read this answer, probably the best on the subject on SO.

Comment: Wow. If only ORM frameworks documentation had such a good explanation - it would make the whole thing easier to swallow! Excellent answer!

Comment: nice explanation, can you explain this for many to many relationship as well. Which side should contain mappedby in many to mnay relationship? cause now there is no owner there is another table which contains fk.

Comment: @eatSleepCode: Not in a comment; please ask a new question

Comment: This is a pretty old post but I am still confused. I understand from this answer that the many side is the owner and the other (the one) side the inverse because the SQL table corresponding to the many side contains the actual foreign key link. 

But the Hibernate documentation tells us: 
"The rules are straightforward: all bi-directional associations need one side as inverse. In a one-to-many association it has to be the many-side, and in many-to-many association you can select either side."
(1.2.6. Working bi-directional links)

So it tells exactly the opposite..

Comment: @klausch: The Hibernate documentation is confusing. Ignore it. Look at the code, the SQL in the database and how the foreign keys work. If you want, you can take a piece of wisdom home: Documentation is a lie. Use the source, Luke.

Comment: When learning Hibernate or whatever framework or technique,  one should not be forced to look at the code... the documentation should be correct and well written and it appears that this is a major flaw in the Hibernate documentation which created lots of confusion in my understanding of mapping logic... This really should be corrected IMHO.

Comment: @AaronDigulla good answer but you could also explains how this works when there's more than a relation between two entities. For example between two nodes in a tree where the nodes can contain a subgraph there may be a relation "parent-child" and a relation "container node, contained nodes". How would this work ?

Answer (score 46):

Unbelievably, in 3 years nobody has answered your excellent question with examples of both ways to map the relationship.

As mentioned by others, the "owner" side contains the pointer (foreign key) in the database. You can designate either side as the owner, however, if you designate the One side as the owner, the relationship will not be bidirectional (the inverse aka "many" side will have no knowledge of its "owner"). This can be desirable for encapsulation/loose coupling:

```
// "One" Customer owns the associated orders by storing them in a customer_orders join table
public class Customer {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Order> orders;
}

// if the Customer owns the orders using the customer_orders table,
// Order has no knowledge of its Customer
public class Order {
    // @ManyToOne annotation has no "mappedBy" attribute to link bidirectionally
}
```

The only bidirectional mapping solution is to have the "many" side own its pointer to the "one", and use the @OneToMany "mappedBy" attribute. Without the "mappedBy" attribute Hibernate will expect a double mapping (the database would have both the join column and the join table, which is redundant (usually undesirable)).

```
// "One" Customer as the inverse side of the relationship
public class Customer {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Order> orders;
}

// "many" orders each own their pointer to a Customer
public class Order {
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Comment: In your unidirectional example, JPA expects an extra customer_orders table to exist. With JPA2 you can use the @JoinColumn annotation (which I seem to use often) on the orders field of Customer to denote the database foreign key column in the Order table that should be used. This way you have a unidirectional relation in Java while still having a foreign key column in the Order table. So in the Object world, the Order doesn't know about Customer while in the database world, the Customer doesn't know about Order.

Comment: To be uber-complete, you could show the bidirectional case where customer is the owning side of the relationship.

Answer (score 37):

The entity which has the table with foreign key in the database is the owning entity and the other table, being pointed at, is the inverse entity.

Comment: even simpler: Owner is the table with the FK Column

Comment: Simple and good explanation. Any side can be made Owner. If we use mappedBy in Order.java ,on Customer field <Remove mappedby from Customer.java> then a new table will be created something like Order_Customer which will have 2 columns. ORDER_ID and CUSTOMER_ID.

Answer (score 15):

Simple rules of bidirectional relationships:

1.For many-to-one bidirectional relationships, the many side is always the owning side of the relationship. Example: 1 Room has many Person (a Person belongs one Room only) -> owning side is Person

2.For one-to-one bidirectional relationships, the owning side corresponds to the side that contains the corresponding foreign key.

3.For many-to-many bidirectional relationships, either side may be the owning side.

Hope can help you.

Comment: Why do we need to have an owner and an inverse at all? We already have the meaningful concepts of one-side and many-side and it doesn't matter who's the owner in many-to-many situations. What are the consequences of the decision? It's hard to believe that someone as left-brained as a database engineer decided to coin these redundant concepts.

Answer (score 4):

For two Entity Classes Customer and Order , hibernate will create two tables.

Possible Cases:

1. mappedBy is not used in Customer.java and Order.java Class then->

   At customer side a new table will be created[name = CUSTOMER_ORDER] which will keep mapping of CUSTOMER_ID and ORDER_ID. These are primary keys of Customer and Order Tables.
   At Order side an additional column is required to save the corresponding Customer_ID record mapping.
2. mappedBy is used in Customer.java [As given in problem statement] 
   Now additional table[CUSTOMER_ORDER] is not created. Only one column in Order Table
3. mappedby is used in Order.java
   Now additional table will be created by hibernate.[name = CUSTOMER_ORDER]
   Order Table will not have additional column [Customer_ID ] for mapping.

Any Side can be made Owner of the relationship. But its better to choose xxxToOne side.

Coding effect - > Only Owning side of entity can change relationship status. In below example BoyFriend class is owner of the relationship. even if Girlfriend wants to break-up , she can't.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "BoyFriend21")
public class BoyFriend21 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Boy_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Boy_ID", sequenceName = "Boy_ID_SEQUENCER", initialValue = 10,allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "BOY_NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private GirlFriend21 girlFriend;

    public BoyFriend21(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BoyFriend21() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BoyFriend21(String name, GirlFriend21 girlFriend) {
        this.name = name;
        this.girlFriend = girlFriend;
    }

    public GirlFriend21 getGirlFriend() {
        return girlFriend;
    }

    public void setGirlFriend(GirlFriend21 girlFriend) {
        this.girlFriend = girlFriend;
    }
}

import org.hibernate.annotations.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity 
@Table(name = "GirlFriend21")
public class GirlFriend21 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Girl_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Girl_ID", sequenceName = "Girl_ID_SEQUENCER", initialValue = 10,allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "GIRL_NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy = "girlFriend")
    private BoyFriend21 boyFriends = new BoyFriend21();

    public GirlFriend21() {
    }

    public GirlFriend21(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public GirlFriend21(String name, BoyFriend21 boyFriends) {
        this.name = name;
        this.boyFriends = boyFriends;
    }

    public BoyFriend21 getBoyFriends() {
        return boyFriends;
    }

    public void setBoyFriends(BoyFriend21 boyFriends) {
        this.boyFriends = boyFriends;
    }
}


import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main578_DS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
         try {
             configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
         } catch (HibernateException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
        final SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        final BoyFriend21 clinton = new BoyFriend21("Bill Clinton");
        final GirlFriend21 monica = new GirlFriend21("monica lewinsky");

        clinton.setGirlFriend(monica);
        session.save(clinton);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import java.util.List;

public class Main578_Modify {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        try {
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        final SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        final Session session1 = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session1.beginTransaction();

        GirlFriend21 monica = (GirlFriend21)session1.load(GirlFriend21.class,10);  // Monica lewinsky record has id  10.
        BoyFriend21 boyfriend = monica.getBoyFriends();
        System.out.println(boyfriend.getName()); // It will print  Clinton Name
        monica.setBoyFriends(null); // It will not impact relationship

        session1.getTransaction().commit();
        session1.close();

        final Session session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session2.beginTransaction();

        BoyFriend21 clinton = (BoyFriend21)session2.load(BoyFriend21.class,10);  // Bill clinton record

        GirlFriend21 girlfriend = clinton.getGirlFriend();
        System.out.println(girlfriend.getName()); // It will print Monica name.
        //But if Clinton[Who owns the relationship as per "mappedby" rule can break this]
        clinton.setGirlFriend(null);
        // Now if Monica tries to check BoyFriend Details, she will find Clinton is no more her boyFriend
        session2.getTransaction().commit();
        session2.close();

        final Session session3 = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session1.beginTransaction();

        monica = (GirlFriend21)session3.load(GirlFriend21.class,10);  // Monica lewinsky record has id  10.
        boyfriend = monica.getBoyFriends();

        System.out.println(boyfriend.getName()); // Does not print Clinton Name

        session3.getTransaction().commit();
        session3.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Table relationships vs. entity relationships

In a relational database system, there can be only three types of table relationships:

- one-to-many (via a Foreign Key column)
- one-to-one (via a shared Primary Key)
- many-to-many (via a link table with two Foreign Keys referencing two separate parent tables)

So, a `one-to-many` table relationship looks as follows:

[image: one-to-many table relationship]

Note that the relationship is based on the Foreign Key column (e.g., `post_id`) in the child table.

So, there is a single source of truth when it comes to managing a `one-to-many` table relationship.

Now, if you take a bidirectional entity relationship that maps on the `one-to-many` table relationship we saw previously:

[image: Bidirectional One-To-Many entity association]

If you take a look at the diagram above, you can see that there are two ways to manage this relationship.

In the `Post` entity, you have the `comments` collection:

```
@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "post",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

And, in the `PostComment`, the `post` association is mapped as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY
)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
private Post post;
```

So, you have two sides that can change the entity association:

- By adding an entry in the `comments` child collection, a new `post_comment` row should be associated with the parent `post` entity via its `post_id` column.
- By setting the `post` property of the `PostComment` entity, the `post_id` column should be updated as well.

Because there are two ways to represent the Foreign Key column, you must define which is the source of truth when it comes to translating the association state change into its equivalent Foreign Key column value modification.

### MappedBy (a.k.a the inverse side)

The `mappedBy` attribute tells that the `@ManyToOne` side is in charge of managing the Foreign Key column, and the collection is used only to fetch the child entities and to cascade parent entity state changes to children (e.g., removing the parent should also remove the child entities).

> It's called the *inverse side* because it references the child entity property that manages this table relationship.

### Synchronize both sides of a bidirectional association

Now, even if you defined the `mappedBy` attribute and the child-side `@ManyToOne` association manages the Foreign Key column, you still need to synchronize both sides of the bidirectional association.

The best way to do that is to add these two utility methods:

```
public void addComment(PostComment comment) {
    comments.add(comment);
    comment.setPost(this);
}

public void removeComment(PostComment comment) {
    comments.remove(comment);
    comment.setPost(null);
}
```

The [`addComment`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/) and [`removeComment`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/) methods ensure that both sides are synchronized. So, if we add a child entity, the child entity needs to point to the parent and the parent entity should have the child contained in the child collection.