# EJB3 mapped by? whose owning of OR mapping?

Tags: java, orm, jpa

Hello everybody i wonder: when can i use mapped by to indicate whose is owing of relationship in one-to -one or one to many - or many to many relationship mapping with EJB3 (JPA)
example 
i have two table A and B
table A belong to table B
so what i place mapped by for whose table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when can I use mapped by to indicate whose is owing of relationship in one-to -one or one to many - or many to many relationship mapping with EJB3

A relationship can be unidirectional or bidirectional. Within a bidirectional relationship you **must** specify the *owning side* of the relationship in the other class with the `mappedBy` element.

- The *owning* side which is responsible for propagating the update of the relationship to the database. Usually this is the side with the foreign key.
- The *inverse* side maps to the owning side.

From the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 2.1.7 Entity Relationships ...
>
> Relationships may be bidirectional or
>   unidirectional. A bidirectional
>   relationship has both an owning side
>   and an inverse side. A unidirectional
>   relationship has only an owning side.
>   The owning side of a relationship
>   determines the updates to the
>   relationship in the database, as
>   described in section 3.2.3.
>
> The following rules apply to
>   bidirectional relationships:
>
> - The inverse side of a bidirectional relationship must refer to its owning
>     side by use of the `mappedBy` element
>     of the `OneToOne`, `OneToMany`, or
>     `ManyToMany` annotation. The
>     `mappedBy` element designates the
>     property or field in the entity that
>     is the owner of the relationship.
> - The many side of one-to-many / many-to-one bidirectional
>     relationships must be the owning side,
>     hence the `mappedBy` element cannot be
>     specified on the `ManyToOne` annotation.
> - For one-to-one bidirectional relationships, the owning side
>     corresponds to the side that contains
>     the corresponding foreign key.
> - For many-to-many bidirectional relationships either side may be the
>     owning side.

Imagine the following model:

```
@Entity
public class Player {
...
    private Team team;

    @ManyToOne
    public Team getTeam() { return team; }

    ...
}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class Team {
    ...    
    private Set<Player> players = new HashSet<Player();

    public Team() { }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team")
    public Set<Player> getPlayers() { return players; }

    ...    
}
```

In this example, the `mappedBy` attribute shows that a `Player` instance's `team` property maps to the `Team` instance and the `Team` object's identifier will exist as a foreign key column in the PLAYER table. The owning `Player` side of the relationship is responsible for storing the foreign key.

If the `mappedBy` is not used,  the persistence provider will assume that there are two independent relationships:

[image: 2 unidirectional relations]

Which is generally not what you want and might end up getting unexpected behavior (e.g. duplicate rows inserted with many-to-many).

#### Related questions

- [In a bidirectional JPA OneToMany/ManyToOne association, what is meant by “the inverse side of the association”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584521/in-a-bidirectional-jpa-onetomany-manytoone-association-what-is-meant-by-the-inv)
- [JPA: which side should be the owning side in a m:n relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484325/jpa-which-side-should-be-the-owning-side-in-a-mn-relationship)

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 2.1.7 "Entity Relationships"

Answer (score 2):

The mappedBy attribute can be used when the relationship is already define on the other part.

For example, in a One to One relationship between entities A and B:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private B b;

    // Code removed for clarity

}
```

Here, my A class defines the relationship to B. It is a One to One relationship using a join column. If I want B to be linked to A, using this already defined relationship, to establish a bidirectional relationship between my entities, I can use the mappedBy attribute :

```
@Entity
public class B {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="b")
    private A a;

    // Code removed for clarity

}
```

Here, the mappedBy attribute means "I want to defined a One to One relationship, which has already been defined on entity A, on the attribute called 'b'".

In general, the owning side of a bidirectional relationship is the entity mapped to the table containing the join column referencing the other table. In case you are using a join table, any side can be the owning side, it just has to make sense in your data model.