# Are "circular references" in JPA an antipattern?

Tags: java, oop, jpa

Lets say 
Car has a List of Wheel and the same time Wheel have a Car reference to the owner.

```
public class Car{
List<Wheel> wheels;

}

public class Wheel{
Car owner;
}
```

I ask this because in JPA is easy to operate like this rather than query again the database for getting the parent entity.

Comment: No, it isn't an anti pattern, but you should only do this if you need them, if you don't there is no need to have it, specially the car->wheels relationship as it can easily cause 1:N queries to the database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bidirectional relationships like this are perfectly valid and expected in JPA.  That's the whole point of the `mappedBy` property.  This post has a good explanation:

[In a bidirectional JPA OneToMany/ManyToOne association, what is meant by "the inverse side of the association"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584521/in-a-bidirectional-jpa-onetomany-manytoone-association-what-is-meant-by-the-in)

Answer (score 4):

This certainly isn't an anti pattern.

You might even say this is very convenient that it's so easy to implement this with JPA. Two possible queries become very trivial; getting all wheels from a certain car and getting the car for a certain wheel.