# @OneToMany hibernate relationship do not set FK in PostgereSQL database

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have @OneToMany relationship between two tables - Company:

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    private List< User > users = new ArrayList<>();
```

and User:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn( name = "companyId" )
private Company company;
```

The problem is, when I create a company with one user, everything is saved into db. A table company_users is created in db, but company id foreign key is not set in user table. It is still empty. I use spring CruDREpository also, but I don't think it could be a case in this example.
Can you tell me why this FK is not set? This is a Postgres problem? I think the relationship was created in good way.

EDIT:

```
public CompanyDto createOrUpdate( final CompanyDto companyDto )
    {
        Company company = companyModelMapperWrapper.getModelMapper().map( companyDto, Company.class );
        Company saved = companyDao.save( company );
        if ( companyDao.exists( saved.getId() ) )
        {
            logger.info( "Company " + saved.getName() + " has been changed" );
        }

        return companyModelMapperWrapper.getModelMapper().map( saved, CompanyDto.class );
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using to create the user. When you create a user you must set the company on it and save it. That should populate the FK column.

Comment: I think Hibernate should do it automatically? I have a simple crud, where I save company into db with user and I want to connect this entities automatically, Am I right? Btw. I updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Because you specified `@OneToMany( mappedBy = "company")` which means that the `User` is the owner of the relation.

And you must set the relation properly while persisting: [In a bidirectional JPA OneToMany/ManyToOne association, what is meant by "the inverse side of the association"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584521/in-a-bidirectional-jpa-onetomany-manytoone-association-what-is-meant-by-the-in)

Comment: Well I should remove this mapped from @OneToMany?

Comment: No. Just make sure that you're persisting `User` instance with `customer` field set in it. Which you probably should do in `map(companyDto, Company.class);` method.

Comment: But in Company I have a list of users. I should put this company for every user in this list? I thought that Hibernate should do this on it own.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So if I have a company entity with list of users I have to set this company to every user from this list. It is not a good performance solution I think.