# "Mapped By" in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have two entity classes:

> User.java
>
> Address.java

One User can have many addresses (One to Many)
And Many Addresses can belong to one user (Many to One)

```
User.java
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
private Set<Address> userAddresses = new HashSet<Address>();

Address.java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="UserID")
private User user;
```

The problem is that although the values are inserted properly in both table, the foreign key column i.e *UserID* is not being updated.
Can anyone please suggest what is wrong with the above snippet?

Comment: Show the codes that how you set the `Address` 's `user` property.

Comment: @Ken Chan
Hi, I got my mistake , I wasnt saving the user property in the Address.
In **OneToMany** relation, the many side is the owner of the relation right ?
but by specifying `mappedBy=user` we are saying that User is the owning entity.
Can you please explain the above concept ?

Comment: This link clarifies my doubt:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584521/in-a-bidirectional-jpa-onetomany-manytoone-association-what-is-meant-by-the-in

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `targetEntity = Address.class` parameter from the `@OneToMany` annotation. Because:

> If the collection is defined using generics to specify the element type, the associated target entity type need not be specified; otherwise the target entity class must be specified.
>   *http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html*

So it should look like this:

```java
User.java
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
targetEntity=Address.class, mappedBy="user")
private Set<Address> userAddresses = new HashSet<Address>();

Address.java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="UserID")
private User user;
```